# Java Swing - JTable Not Showing in Scroll Pane

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I created a class `Cart` and inside is a JTable and two ArrayLists. For some reason, my JTable is not displaying.

Here is my Cart Class:

```
class Cart {
    ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>(); // Holds the products themselves
    ArrayList<Integer> quantities = new ArrayList<>(); // Holds the quantities themselves
    JTable prdTbl = new JTable(); // The GUI Product Table
    DefaultTableModel prdTblModel = new DefaultTableModel(); // The Table Model
    Object[] columns = {"Description","Price","Quantity","Total"}; // Column Identifiers
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00;$-#,##0.00"); // Decimal Format for formatting USD ($#.##)

    Cart() {
        setTableStyle();
    }

    void renderTable() {        
        // Re-initialize the Table Model
        this.prdTblModel = new DefaultTableModel();

        // Set the Table Style
        setTableStyle();

        // Create a row from each list entry for product and quantity and add it to the Table Model
        for(int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
            Object[] row = new Object[4];

            row[0] = products.get(i).getName();
            row[1] = products.get(i).getPrice();
            row[2] = quantities.get(i);
            row[3] = fmt.format(products.get(i).getPrice() * quantities.get(i));

            this.prdTblModel.addRow(row);
        }

        this.prdTbl.setModel(this.prdTblModel);
    }

    void setTableStyle() {
        this.prdTblModel.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);
        this.prdTbl.setModel(this.prdTblModel);
        this.prdTbl.setBackground(Color.white);
        this.prdTbl.setForeground(Color.black);
        Font font = new Font("Tahoma",1,22);
        this.prdTbl.setFont(font);
        this.prdTbl.setRowHeight(30);
    }

    JTable getTable() {
        renderTable(); // Render Table
        return this.prdTbl;
    }
}
```

Note: some methods have been removed such as addProduct() and removeProduct(), as I feel they aren't necessary. If you need to see them, please ask.

Here is my initialize() method for the Swing Application Window:

```
/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 590, 425);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Cart cart = new Cart();

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, "cell 0 0,grow");

    JPanel cartPanel = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Cart", null, cartPanel, null);
    cartPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow]", "[][grow]"));

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    cartPanel.add(scrollPane, "cell 0 1,grow");

    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String[] item = {"Macadamia", "Hazelnut", "Almond", "Peanut", "Walnut", "Pistachio", "Pecan", "Brazil"};
            Double[] price = {2.00, 1.90, 1.31, 0.85, 1.12, 1.53, 1.25, 1.75};

            int choice = (int) (Math.random() * item.length);

            Product p = new Product(item[choice], price[choice]);

            cart.addProduct(p);
            table = cart.getTable();
        }
    });
    cartPanel.add(btnAdd, "flowx,cell 0 0");

    JButton btnRemove = new JButton("Remove");
    cartPanel.add(btnRemove, "cell 0 0");

    JButton btnClear = new JButton("Clear");
    cartPanel.add(btnClear, "cell 0 0");

}
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something here? It has worked fine like this in the past? I've also tried printing out values at `table = cart.getTable();`, and it seems to be receiving the values fine, so it leads me to believe it has something to do with the Swing `initialize()` rather than my `Cart` class, but just in case I posted the `Cart` class as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're adding the right table? Your code shows:

```
table = new JTable();
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
```

I cannot see where's table declared, further more table contains nothing, no rows no columns, while inside actionListener you initialize table with a new instance:

```
table = cart.getTable();
```

but the scrollPane holds another instance of JTable.

Comment: I just realized that before you posted it. Thank you @ugo

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you never associate your cart with your cartPanel; I think your problem is here:

```
 JPanel cartPanel = new JPanel();
```

you make the new panel but never hook your cart to it. Looks good otherwise.

Good luck!

Comment: You could also associate your new table in initialize() with your cart table if you want to do it that way, as @ugo is suggesting.

Comment: My pleasure @TommyYamakaitis, glad I could help!